# how to get message object from message id in whatsapp cloud api?

Tags: python, api, cloud, whatsapp

I'm new to WhatsApp cloud API. After sending a message to a particular number I get the following response from WhatsApp cloud API.

```
{
  "messages": [{
    "id": "gBEGkYiEB1VXAglK1ZEqA1YKPrU"
  }]
}
```

My question is how do I get my message object back using this id?

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific endpoint to get the message back by it's Id, but You have to set up a Webhook endpoint to track the message status,

See the whole process of how to set up Webhook,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks

Here is the demo of the Webhook endpoint, 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/sample-app-endpoints

Comment: I've already setup webhook but I want message content sent by API itself. @turivishal

Comment: You can not get message content sent by message API, you have to save that content while sending a message, Here I have explained the recording process in answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008570/whatsapp-chats-real-time-recording/73009444#73009444

Comment: what about if I want to know messages sent from other whatsapp client? same as Facebook message_echo?

Comment: @shamaseen, you will receive other clients' messages in the webhook endpoint. i have written a tutorial you can refer https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/whatsapp-business-api-data-api/