# Whatsapp API can't return chats?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I scrolled through their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp) and saw that there's no way of receiving your chats. It says something about them just lasting 24 hours?

Did I read/understand it right and is there no way of receiving the chats with the included messages? If I wanted to reload the "chat-page" and for the messages to still be there do I need to save the messages myself in a database?

Comment: Yes, you need to save it in your database, they don't provide any list of chats, refer to the similar question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008570/whatsapp-chats-real-time-recording/73009444#73009444